# logback.xml root level doesn't work when another logger uses different level

Tags: java, logback

My original logback.xml:

```
    <configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    
      <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
          <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, PST} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}:%line - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
      </appender>
    
      <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
      </root>
    </configuration>
```

It worked fine: It logged everything from DEBUG level and up to console. Now I want to keep that going and also have only INFO and higher severity messages logged into a separate file. I added the following to the above but now am getting no more DEBUG messages at all:

```
      <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>myLog.log</file>        
        <encoder>
          <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, PST} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}:%line - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
      </appender>
    
      <logger name="myLogger" level="info" >
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
      </logger>
```

Now only INFO level and higher are logged in both places. What is wrong here?

Version is 1.2.10

Answer (score -1):

What you want is a filter on your Appender. See: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html

What you did was change the logger, which is shared among all appenders. This normally done to change part of the loggers like: com.company.framework to have a different lowest level of log messages instead of the default from the root logger, if I recall correctly.